# unable to set xhr.responseType using chrome 43 beta

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, chromium

I have some request that I'm sending the server, and I'm setting the XMLHttpRequest object I created as follows:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = "blob";
```

This works just fine on the current chrome 42 version, but when I try to run the same code on chrome 43 beta, the xhr.responseType fails to be set with the value "blob". I tried other kinds of response types but it just doesn't work.

Did anyone faced this issue too? 
Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems we use pdf.js package in our app, which has a compatibility.js file that defines a setter function "responseTypeSetter", that doesn't let us to set the XMLHttpRequest's responseType to 'blob' or anything else.

Upgrading compatibility.js to a newer version had solved this problem.